# Linear Approximate of Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
Block DF
0     1.2
1     2.3
4     4.2
5     5.6
6     4.3
10    2.2
```

How to find out linear approx. value DF of Block 7

```
(7,???)
```

using the closest two data point

```
(6, 4.3) 
(10, 2.2)?
```

How to implement to find the two closest data point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.interp` function to find interpolations:

```
import numpy as np
np.interp(7, df.block, df.DF)
# >>> 3.775
```

More info [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

You could also use `interp1d` from the `scipy.interpolate` package:

```
from scipy.interpolation import interp1d
f = interp1d(df.block, df.DF)
xnew = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True)
zip(xnew, f(xnew))
# [(0.0, 1.2),
# (1.0, 2.2999999999999998),
# (2.0, 2.9333333333333331),
# (3.0, 3.5666666666666664),
# (4.0, 4.2000000000000002),
# (5.0, 5.5999999999999996),
# (6.0, 4.2999999999999998),
# (7.0, 3.7749999999999999),
# (8.0, 3.25),
# (9.0, 2.7250000000000001),
# (10.0, 2.2000000000000002)]
```

Comment: can this function applicable for datetime?

Comment: Assuming the `datetime` is valued as an integer. But you'll probably need to round the interpolation back to integers so that it's a valid `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

I saw the tag 'pandas' on the question and I tried to use Pandas for this implementation. Check out the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([1.2,2.3,np.nan,np.nan,4.2,5.6,4.3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2.2], index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
ans = s.interpolate(method='linear')
print(ans)
```

The output should be:

0     1.200000
   1     2.300000
   2     2.933333
   3     3.566667
   4     4.200000
   5     5.600000
   6     4.300000
   7     3.775000
   8     3.250000
   9     2.725000
   10    2.200000
   dtype: float64

Comment: try this: `s = pd.Series([1.2,2.3,4.2,5.6,4.3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2.2], index=[0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])`; `ans = s.interpolate(method='linear')` - then you'll have the same results ...

Comment: @maxU I tried you solution but it generate an error saying that you need to have the same number of number on Series and Index. However, you gave me an insight of how to fix the problem. I just edited my answer.